# Best way to handle multiple checks ruby

Tags: ruby, colors, rgb, hsl

So I'm trying to write a converter for HSL to RGB (and eventually into hex)
I'm following this [colorspace conversion theory](https://www.niwa.nu/2013/05/math-behind-colorspace-conversions-rgb-hsl/) and I seem to be stuck on step 6

> Now we need to do up to 3 tests to select the correct formula for each
>   color channel. Let’s start with Red.
>
> test 1 – If 6 x temporary_R is smaller then 1, Red = temporary_2 +
>   (temporary_1 – temporary_2) x 6 x temporary_R In the case the first
>   test is larger then 1 check the following
>
> test 2 – If 2 x temporary_R is smaller then 1, Red = temporary_1 In
>   the case the second test also is larger then 1 do the following
>
> test 3 – If 3 x temporary_R is smaller then 2, Red = temporary_2 +
>   (temporary_1 – temporary_2) x (0.666 – temporary_R) x 6 In the case
>   the third test also is larger then 2 you do the following
>
> Red = temporary_2
>
> Ok lets do it for our Red value
>
> 6 x temporary_R = 6 x 0.869 = 5.214, so it’s larger then 1, we need to
>   do test 2 2 x temporary_R = 2 x 0.869 = 1.738, it’s also larger then
>   1, we need to do test 3 3 x temporary_R = 3 x 0.869 = 2.607, it’s
>   larger then 2, so we go for the last formula Red = temporary_2 =
>   0.0924 which rounded down is 0.09, which is a number we recognize from the RGB to HSL conversion

So far I've monkey patched a function to take my HSL colours

```
def toRGB(hue, sat, lum)
  temp_1 =
  case lum
   when lum < 0.0
     lum x (1.0 * sat)
   when lum > 0.0
     (lum + sat) - lum
  end
  temp_2 = (2 * lum) - temp_1.to_f
  h = (hue/360.0).round(4)
  temp_r = (h + 0.333).round(4)
  temp_r = temp_r + 1 if temp_r < 0
  temp_r = temp_r - 1 if temp_r > 1
  temp_g = h 
  temp_b = (h - 0.333).round(4)
  temp_b = temp_b + 1 if temp_b < 0
  temp_b = temp_b - 1 if temp_b > 1
  red = 
  #test 1
  #test 2
  #test 3
  "#{red}"
end
```

I was trying to use a `case` statement

```
red = 
  case temp_r
    when 6 * temp_r < 1
      temp_2 + (temp_1 - temp_2) * 6 * temp_r
    when 2 * temp_r < 1
      temp_1
    when 3 * temp_r < 2
      temp_2 + (temp_1 - temp_2) * (0.666 - temp_r * 6)
  end
```

but then I started re-reading the instructions and now I can't really see a way to do what I need in ruby. Maybe I'm over-thinking it.

If you want to see the rest of my code in context you [can see it here](https://repl.it/@LeggoMyEcho/AltruisticBelovedSkunk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I noticed in your code snippet:

You are mixing two types of switch case statement in ruby.

```
case a
when 1..5
 "It's between 1 and 5"
when 6
 "It's 6"
end

case
when a > 1 && a < 5
 "It's between 1 and 5"
when a == 6
 "It's 6"
end
```

See a difference, in first case when you directly compare cases, you've to mention the variable name you're comparing with, while in second case you're comparing with true & false condition by explicitly putting a condition on your variable so you don't need to put it next to case.

The second thing is as per your condition statement, you'll need an else case in your case statement.

```
red = 
  case
    when 6 * temp_r < 1
      temp_2 + (temp_1 - temp_2) * 6 * temp_r
    when 2 * temp_r < 1
      temp_1
    when 3 * temp_r < 2
      temp_2 + (temp_1 - temp_2) * (0.666 - temp_r * 6)
    else
      temp_2
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I tried that case statement out and while it seems to work; when applied to the other two values they all output the same thing. 
I'm not sure where it's getting stuck.
After removing the `else` though it outputs nothing so I think all 3 are defaulting there.

Comment: @LeggoMyEcho I checked your code at repl.it, you're doing the same mistake again, there won't be a variable after case when you're doing the comparison which results to true/false. Fixed it for you at https://repl.it/@anuraginvest5/AltruisticBelovedSkunk

Comment: Thanks! I'm so used to having to have a variable when you use a case statement. But now I understand. Since it's comparing the `temp` variables within it already I don't need to compare anything to it. I appreciate everything! Now I think i need to start tweaking some things because now the output is slightly different than the original

Comment: @LeggoMyEcho Welcome, you can accept the answer if it solves your question.